# Give precedence to break-after: avoid in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, page-break, page-break-inside

I have multiple blocks of content I want to print them while choosing when to make my page breaks. I want to avoid breaks inside my blocks obviously, but I also want my title blocks not to break just before my contents.

For example, I have 3 divs and I want the second and the third to be on the same page while also avoiding breaks inside.

I tried:

```css
.first {
    height: 20cm;
    border: solid red 5pt;
}
.second {
    height: 2cm;
    border: solid blue 5pt;
    break-after: avoid;
}
.third {
    height: 30cm;
    border: solid green 5pt;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</body>
```

This works exactly as expected on chrome. When I print, the first div is on page 1, the second and third are on page 2, and the end of the third on page 3.

On firefox, though, I got the first and second on page 1, the third div overlapping page 2 and 3. Whatever I try, break-inside is always putting the third div on the next page, ignoring break-after.
The only workaround I've found is removing it from the third div and grouping div 2 and 3 together in another div with `break-inside: avoid;` but I'd rather avoid that if possible.